# What is the use of ElementLocatorFactory and FieldDecorator in Page Factory?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please explain how to use `ElementLocatorFactory` and `FieldDecorator` in `PageFactory` using `Selenium`? I am unable to understand it and request you to explain this in layman terms.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use the `PageFactory`, the webelements instances are actually proxies and the elements have to be found before you call a method on them.

The getting part is encapsulated in the `ElementLocator` for each field. The `ElementLocatorFactory` provides these for each element. This factory needs a `SearchContext` provided to the factory constructor. The driver implements the `SearchContext` (the method findelement) or even a webelement. The `By` part that is how to look for them, is retrieved by reflection `API` on the fields of the pageobject.

Assigning the proxies to the fields is handled by the `FieldDecorator`, which requires the `ElementLocatorFactory`. The `decorate()` method called for each webelement field returns a proxy which is set for that field. When a method is called on the webelement it actually is called on the proxy. The proxy intercepts this call to use the `SearchContext.findElement` method to find the actual element and then calls your original method.

So one can create custom `ElementLocatorFactory` and `FieldDecorator` to pass to the `PageFactory`.

For a code-level explanation - http://www.alechenninger.com/2014/07/a-case-study-of-javas-dynamic-proxies_14.html.